# Get Latitude And Longitude in Session With Laravel and Set Default Value?

Tags: laravel, session

Get Latitude And Longitude in Session With Laravel  and Set Default Value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if (Session::get('lat') && Session::get('longi') != null){
    $s_lat=Session::get('lat');
    $s_longi=Session::get('longi');
    $array=[$s_lat,$s_longi,$s_lat];
}
else{
    $array=['10','0']; //default lat long
}
```